# Understanding Spark MLlib ALS.trainImplicit input format

Tags: python, pyspark, collaborative-filtering

I`m trying to make a recommender system based on purchase history using trainImplicit. My input is in domain [1, +inf) (the sum of views and purchases).

So the element of my input RDD looks like this: `[(user_id,item_id),rating] --> [(123,5564),6]` - the user(id = 123) interacted with the item(id=5564) 6 times.

Should I add to my RDD elements such as `[(user_id,item_id),rating] --> [(123,2222),0]`, meaning that given user has never interacted with given item or the ALS.implicitTrain does this implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it not necessary (for implicit) and shouldn't be done (for explicit) so in this case bass only data you actually have.

Comment: Do you mean that the model trained on the dataset with zeroes will give roughly the same recommendations as the model trained on the dataset without zeroes? Or these additional zeroes will influence the result?

Comment: In implicit it shouldn't affect the results, in explicit it will significantly affect the result.